# HammerJS Swipe not working on Mobile Device or Google Chrome on Device Mode

Tags: angular, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, hammer.js

I have a simple code to make the Web Site swipeable, It's working when I test on Google Chrome on Desktop, but when I'm going to test on my mobile device or on Google Chrome DevTools Device Mode it's not working.

I tried to change the values of HammerGestureConfig overrides, but when I try to change to swipeleft or swiperight I got an error, only accept the swipe override.

```
...
import * as Hammer from 'hammerjs';
import { HammerGestureConfig, HAMMER_GESTURE_CONFIG, BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { SwipeComponent } from './components/swipe/swipe.component';

export class HammerConfig extends HammerGestureConfig {
  overrides = {
    swipe: { direction: Hammer.DIRECTION_ALL },
  } as any;
}

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    ...
    SwipeComponent,
  ],
  ...
  providers: [
    AuthService,
    {
      provide: HAMMER_GESTURE_CONFIG,
      useClass: HammerConfig
    }
  ],
})
export class AppModule { }
```

```
<div
  (swipeleft)="navigateForwardTo(forward)"
  (swiperight)="navigateBackTo(back)">
  <ng-content></ng-content>
  <app-navigation-arrows 
    [back]="back"
    [backEnabled]="backEnabled"
    [forwardEnabled]="forwardEnabled"
    [forward]="forward">
  </app-navigation-arrows>
</div>
```

Answer (score 6):

I had to change the inputClass to Hammer.TouchInput

```
export class HammerConfig extends HammerGestureConfig  {
  buildHammer(element: HTMLElement): HammerManager {
     return new Hammer.Manager(element, {
      touchAction: 'auto',
      inputClass: Hammer.TouchInput,
      recognizers: [
        [Hammer.Swipe, {
          direction: Hammer.DIRECTION_HORIZONTAL
        }]
      ]
    });
  }
}
```